# What in the world is happening on Handbrake on my Mac?

Tags: video, encoding

I have used handbrake once successfully, to rip my first season of Boardwalk Empire to my Mac. But now any time after that first successful try, it gives me images like this: [image: pixelated image] where it is all pixelated and the fading between scenes is very jagged-y. What is happening now?

Comment: It's hard to provide a useful answer for this without some more information. It would be helpful if you posted the settings you're using, and some information about the source (i.e. is it Blu-ray, DVD, something else).

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove the VLC player ?

Because HandBrake no longer includes the libraries needed to decrypt commercial DVDs, you’ll also need to install the VLC media player.

To get the 64-bit benefits from HandBrake, you’ll need to have a 64-bit version of VLC as well.

The standard download is a Universal Binary and contains both 32- and 64-bit code for Intel Macs—if you want to save some disk space, you can download the [VLC specific version here.](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html)

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest version of VLC and libdvdcss and this solved the pixelated issues.  Not sure which one corrected the problem but Handbrake is working correctly again.  One note: you may have to change your security settings in System Preferences>Security & Privacy>General to "Anywhere" in order for libdvdcss to be installed on your mac.

Answer (score -2):

Answer: don't use Handbrake. Use this: http://www.macxdvd.com/dvd-ripper-mac-free/

Comment: Why? What does it do better?

Comment: Oh dear. No. Macxdvd is a $35 software. It works fine, but it has nothing to do with handbrake. They do have a free verison, but it only works for 5 minutes of your DVD. Then you have to pay